# Post data to Custom URL on Edit Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run a trigger to post data to a URL when a value is added in a Google Sheet.

But as the UrlFetchApp.fetch() does not work on onEdit trigger, is there a turnaround we can do , so I get the value whenever a new value is added in the sheet

Comment: You might check this [issue tracker 1](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=185) that you may use customFunction and connect it to `onEdit()` to make it work. Note that [issue tracker 2](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1324), UrlFetchApp is no longer supported in a simple onEdit trigger. You can try the work around that can be found in the issue tracker 1 but as a Googler said that they "disabled Urlfetch in  onEdit triggers because to enable this feature may introduce a security concern." Hope this info helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot yes thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot how can I mark this question as answered?

Comment: An "installed" "On Edit" trigger has different permissions than a "simple" "On Edit" trigger.  Change the function name from the reserved function name of "onEdit()" to something else, and then click the Resources menu, and "Current project's triggers."

Comment: @StacyThompson Do you mean that you'll accept my comment if posted as answer?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot yes, I was able to create a trigger

Comment: ok, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check this [issue tracker 1](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=185) that you may use customFunction and connect it to **`onEdit()`** to make it work. Note that [issue tracker 2](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1324), UrlFetchApp is no longer supported in a simple onEdit trigger. You can try the work around that can be found in the issue tracker 1 but mentioned that they "disabled Urlfetch in onEdit triggers because to enable this feature may introduce a security concern."

Hope this info helps.